# install multiple versions of protoc on MacOS

Tags: homebrew, protocol-buffers

I'm looking for a way to have multiple versions of protoc available on my Mac (Sierra).

On Windows I have my .exe files on the path whereas the filenames contain the version.

On Mac I found (with brew) versions 2.5, 2.6 and 3.1. If I want to have both 2.5 and 2.6 available how would I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install all of them with:

```
brew install protobuf@2.5 protobuf@2.6 protobuf@3.1
```

Add `protobuf` to the list to get the latest version (3.4.1 at the time of this writing).

However formulae with specific versions (those that end with `@<version>`) aren’t symlinked in standard locations so you’ll need to use their specific prefix to use them, e.g.:

```
$ `brew --prefix protobuf@2.5`/bin/protoc ...
$ `brew --prefix protobuf@2.6`/bin/protoc ...
$ `brew --prefix protobuf@3.1`/bin/protoc ...
```

You could also use aliases:

```
$ alias protoc25="$(brew --prefix protobuf@2.5)/bin/protoc"
$ protoc25 ...
```

Homebrew does so not to get conflicts between installed versions. The non-fixed formula is correctly symlinked in `/usr/local/bin` or similar so it works unprefixed:

```
$ protoc ...
```

If you use a program that relies on `protoc` but don’t want to modify it to use a specific version you can add the relevant path to your `PATH` to ensure it uses it:

```
$ PATH="$(brew --prefix protobuf@2.5)/bin:$PATH"
$ protoc ...  # protoc 2.5
```

Comment: This no longer works. Older versions were removed from homebrew.